# "do if" for combine multiple variables into one in R

Tags: r

1. I want to migrate from SPSS the syntax "do if, compute, else, compute" to R

   - So, in SPSS I have:`do if (Var1=1 or Var2=1 or Var3=1).
                        compute VarNew1 = 1.
                        ELSE. compute VarNew1 = 0.`
   - Then SPSS recode again `RECODE VarNew1 (0=0) (1=2). 
                             RECODE VarNew2 (0=0) (1=3). 
                             RECODE VarNew3 (0=0) (1=4). 
                             EXECUTE.`
2. After SPSS create VarNew1, VarNew2, using the same process as above and combining with several categorical variables (VarNew1 coming from Var1,Var2,Var3, and VarNew2 coming from Var4, Var5, Var7). We finally arrive to the following code: `COMPUTE VarNewFinal=MAX(VarNew1,VarNew2,VarNew3).`
3. As you can see, what the SPSS does is to check Var1, Var2 and Var3 for the code "1" and recode to a new variable "VarNew1". And recode again to convert the code into "VarNewFinal" which contains the codes "2", "3", "4". The final variable it is used to plot or frequency table.
4. In R I tried with `VarNew1 <- data.frame(Var1,Var2,Var3,na.rm=T)
   VarNew1 <- ifelse(VarNew1==4, 1, 2)`

   - I think I can skip the second recodification made by SPPS.
   - After that process I do not get a new variable but and object that I cannot use to plot.
   - `VarNewFinal <- data.frame(VarNew1,VarNew2,VarNew3)
     sjt.frq(VarNewFinal)`

Thanks for your attention, any help will be much appreciated as we try hard to move from paid to open source software. You can also make some references to something I can read about how to deal with categorical variables, using multiple codes to bring one single variable.

Comment: Looks like there are a number of questions.  For the first one `df1$VarNew1 <- with(df1, ifelse(Var1==1|Var2==1|Var3==1, 1, 0))`

Comment: Yeah, I think you should probably split this question up and ask each question separately...

Comment: Dear akrun and SamB, thanks for the follow up. After reading tons of ways, I finally got to the same conclusion akrun gave me. Please take in count that in this migration I have also to teach R and so, the more simple and look like SPSS I can work, the better my colleagues will take R as useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that I think might be helpful. There's probably a whole bunch of ways to attack this, but I think this is reasonably clear as a starting point:

```
# make some example data:
set.seed(18189)
df1 <- setNames(
  data.frame(replicate(6,sample(0:1,5,replace=TRUE))),
       paste0("Var",1:6))

# calculate your columns
df1$Final <- pmax(
  ifelse(rowSums(df1[c("Var1","Var2","Var3")]==1) > 0, 2, 0),
  ifelse(rowSums(df1[c("Var4","Var5","Var6")]==1) > 0, 3, 0)
)
```

Example dataset with added result:

```
#  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Final
#1    0    1    0    0    0    1     3
#2    1    1    1    0    0    0     2
#3    0    1    0    0    1    0     3
#4    0    0    0    1    0    1     3
#5    0    0    0    1    1    0     3
```

This essentially checks if Var1-3 has a `1` anywhere in each row, if Var4-6 has a `1` anywhere in each row, and then takes the highest set using the labels (`2` or `3`) that you specified. `pmax` just takes the max of a set of vectors comparing each value - e.g. `pmax(c(1,2,3),c(0,2,4))`

If you want to get all functional and make this more easily extensible, we can get a bit more complex:

```
vars <- list(c("Var1","Var2","Var3"), c("Var4","Var5","Var6") )
matchval <- function(x,y,data,val) ifelse(rowSums(data[x]==val) > 0, y, 0)
do.call(pmax, Map(matchval, x=vars, y=seq_along(vars), data=list(df1), val=1))
#[1] 2 1 2 2 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much to all. The job is done when R goes to check the condition in each row in an object made of multiple variables at the same time and produces the outcome in a new variable. Let say: `# produce some random vars
D1 <- seq(1, 4, length=10)
D2 <- seq(1, 2, length=10)
D3 <- seq(1, 4, length=10)
D4 <- seq(1, 2, length=10)
DF <- data.frame(D1,D2,D3,D4) 
DF` then `DF$D8 <- ifelse(D1==1|D2==1|D3==1|D4==1,1,0)` results in one new var with the expected outcome. But if I do `DF$D8<- ifelse(DF[c("D1","D2","D3","D4")]==1,1,0)` the result is not a new variable but a four new columns.

Comment: So, what if we have 200 variables to check? I think thelatemail has a solution but a bit complex, yes. Thank you again.

Comment: @luispenutt - the rowSums part is important as that makes sure you are checking for a value across the set of variables. Your second example has removed that key middle section, giving a different result.

Comment: If you have 200 variables, you can reference vars like `paste0("D",1:200)` instead of typing the whole set out.

Comment: The big benefit of R is that you can break down the components of a statement and see the result live, before building up an entire block of code. Using your example, look at `(vars <- paste0("D",1:4))` then `DF[vars]==1` then `rowSums(DF[vars]==1)` then `rowSums(DF[vars]==1) > 0` then `as.numeric(rowSums(DF[vars]==1) > 0)`